# See the page as a search engine

Tags: jquery, search-engine

When you view the source of a page, if you have jQuery operating on it then you will see if differently to the way you'd see it when inspecting an element. Which way does a search engine like Google see it?

I have a slideshow that sits in a division. The jQuery creates the image tag and so I wondering if Google would see the alt attribute on the image if it's created by jQuery.

Comment: You should google it

Comment: I couldn't find an answer that was useful. They were all answers to a different question. That's why I came here, to try and ask the question and get an answer to the right question.

Comment: Disable css and javascript in your browser.  Or use Lynx.

Comment: I used Lynx and using the answer by Rakesh G R I can see what I was trying to find out. Thank's for the Lynx suggestion.

Comment: Google is able to crawl most, if not all, dynamic content. `The jQuery creates the image tag and so I wondering if Google would see the alt attribute on the image if it's created by jQuery` Ya it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines like google* are only able to see the static content of any page(the view source output).

This can obviously cause a lot of problems with js rendered pages(I had them with ember).
Techniques like server side rendering(Ex.Fastboot) are used to 'try' to overcome this.
*-Used as an example of search engines only. Do not mean in any way to specify any limitations on the particular search engine.

Comment: What??? Google e.g is able to index disqus comments so what?! A quick search gave me this: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Comment: @A.Wolff ah...I did mention about server side rendering didn't I?
Now...with something like disqus there are two levels of bot crawling: First inside an IFrame(if you have embedded code to your site)...which is something google can do though there used to be known association issues and then the server side rendered page(which btw is optional with disqus)...and yes a special case with google is that it actually renders pages(earlier I was talking about search engines in general)

Comment: Ok disqus 'could' be a bad example but from my own experience, google is able to crawl any js/jq dynamic content. Otherwise, it would be too easy to game it. But that's quite a broad subject, it really depends of what we call 'dynamic' content. OP talk about dynamic image and AFAIK, google will index it.

Comment: You did read my comment fully didn't you?...and I have also added a little note to my answer

Comment: The slideshow that I'm using is found here:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

It doesn't all alt tags to the images but I changed the jQuery to do it. Would a search engine see it. I can't see it on view source or on Lynx but to above comments suggest that I still may be able to see it.

Comment: understand that search engines come in all sizes...for one like google this one is too easy...like @A.Wolff said it all comes to what you call dynamic content...your page uses js to render a part of it sure...but it doesn't have any "dynamic" dependencies whatsoever....it is the same page everytime...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying but this is true. I assume some of jQuery idea is for DHTML to make it easier for users to customise it but the real idea of the jQuery is really just to make the slideshow fade from one image to the other along with a few other features like loop, description, pause and swipe navigation.

Comment: what I mean to say is that is unlike 'purely static' content your page does change visually...but all it's content or the data that generates the content does not change...contrast this with a case where the the images are served dynamically or the image urls are fetched by a ajax call...or something that requires user input...

Comment: Yes the content does not change so does it mean that the images can be indexed and it's worth adjusting the code to give them their alt tags?